# constexpr works on Ubuntu, but not MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, ubuntu, c++14

I have this code which compiles fine on Ubuntu, but when I try to compile it on MacOS I get this error:

```
Constexpr variable 'HeuristicNames' must be initialized by a constant expression
```

```cpp
#define LSHPair std::pair<const char *, LISTSCHED_HEURISTIC>
static constexpr LSHPair HeuristicNames[] = {
    LSHPair("CP", LSH_CP),    LSHPair("LUC", LSH_LUC),
    LSHPair("UC", LSH_UC),    LSHPair("NID", LSH_NID),
    LSHPair("CPR", LSH_CPR),  LSHPair("ISO", LSH_ISO),
    LSHPair("SC", LSH_SC),    LSHPair("LS", LSH_LS),
    LSHPair("LLVM", LSH_LLVM)};
```

`LISTSCHED_HEURISTIC` is an `enum`.

I take this error to mean that some part of the right hand side of the assignment is not a `constexpr`, so the resulting variable can't be a `constexpr`. However I don't have a firm enough grasp of the rules around `constexpr` to understand why, or how to fix it.

I also don't get why this is different on MacOS than on Ubuntu. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Can you tell us what compiler are you using on MacOs and which one in Ubuntu?  I assume Clang and gcc respectively, I tried some versions of the 2 (https://godbolt.org/z/dwJUee) and I can compile without any issue.

Comment: Interesting, the ctor of std::pair became constexpr with C++14, can it be that you are using C++11 in one case and C++14 in another? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts I was wondering that as well, so I tried with C++14 on MacOS and still got an error.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts Turns out I didn't do it right the first time. Once I _actually_ tried with C++14 it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you do not need macro.
You could define type

```
using LSHPair =  std::pair<const char *, LISTSCHED_HEURISTIC>;
```

Or just use brace initialization, what is much more clean:

```cpp
using LSHPair =  std::pair<const char *, LISTSCHED_HEURISTIC>;

static constexpr LSHPair HeuristicNames[] = {
    {"CP", LSH_CP},
    {"LUC", LSH_LUC},
    {"UC", LSH_UC},   
    {"NID", LSH_NID},
    {"CPR", LSH_CPR},
    {"ISO", LSH_ISO},
    {"SC", LSH_SC}, 
    {"LS", LSH_LS},
    {"LLVM", LSH_LLVM}
};
```

As @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts point out [constructor of `std::pair` is a `constexpr` since `c++14`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

I've test this on my Mac OS and apparently clang there works a bit differently then on Linux (as [shown on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/mWBsDs)):

```sh
Marek R$ g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
main.cpp:17:26: error: constexpr variable 'HeuristicNames' must be initialized by a constant expression
static constexpr LSHPair HeuristicNames[] = {
                         ^                  ~
main.cpp:18:5: note: non-constexpr constructor 'pair<char const (&)[3], LISTSCHED_HEURISTIC, false>' cannot be used in a constant expression
    {"CP", LSH_CP},
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:446:5: note: declared here
    pair(_U1&& __u1, _U2&& __u2)
    ^
1 error generated.
Marek R$ g++ main.cpp -std=c++14
Marek R$
```

So MacOS clang is right.

Problem must be on header files and versioning them depending on C++ standard.
Most probably same header files of standard library are used for clang and gcc are used on Linux. On Mac `std::pair` constructor is prefixed by macro `_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11` which definition changes deeding on C++ standard enabled. On Linux you have to check by yourself how it is done.

Comment: You say "MacoOS clang is right", is that true when targeting C++14? Shouldn't that then work as a `constexpr`? I tried it and still got the error, but I'm not super confident I'm using Xcode correctly - I may not have actually changed the language standard to C++14.

Comment: I does work with C++14, see last 2 lines of my terminal logs. When `-std=c++14` is used there is zero errors or warnings.

Comment: Ah! You're right. I was in fact doing it wrong. I had changed the language standard for the wrong target. Thanks so much for the help.